# Powershell for listing local admins on network

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, administrator

I am using the following Powershell from http://iislogs.com/steveschofield/2009/01/09/list-local-administrators-on-a-machine-using-powershell-adsi/ to extract the local and domain admin accounts configured in PC and servers of an internal network.

Powershell script is below:

```
function LogToFile ([string]$strFileName, [string]$strComputer)
{
 Add-Content $strFileName $strComputer
}

$strComputer = “server1.loc.mydomain.com”
$computer = [ADSI](“WinNT://” + $strComputer + “,computer”)
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(“Administrators”)
$members= $Group.psbase.invoke(“Members”) | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember(“Name”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}

ForEach($user in $members)

{
Write-Host $user
$a = $strComputer + “!” + $user.ToString()
LogToFile “C:\local-admins.txt” $a
}
```

When executed, it produces results in the txt file in following format:

```
server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator
server1.loc.mydomain.com!JohnDoe
server1.loc.mydomain.com!Support
server1.loc.mydomain.com!Domain Administrators
```

1. Can someone help me to change the output on txt file, so the results are shown in this format:

   ```
   server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator!JohnDoe!Support!Domain Administrators
   ```

If reported in this way, then I can easily export to csv and work with it.
It'd be super cool if this can be transformed to export on CSV in desired format instead of txt.

2. How to make the code on line 6 so e.g. if I want to scan the whole subnet which has names: server1, server2, .... server38... I don't have to manually change that line for each machine. I tried server*, server[*] and it gives me errors.

I am a complete novice in PS, but trying to piece things together to address my needs and hope you may provide me with needed help.

Thanks.

Comment: `$a = @($strComputer;$members) -join '!'`

Comment: It's almost there. But it now produces the desired output in same lines depending on how many admins are. E.g. if there are 4 admins, the output is ( the > are added only for clearer emphasis)

>    server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator!JohnDoe!Support!Domain Administrators

>    server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator!JohnDoe!Support!Domain Administrators

>    server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator!JohnDoe!Support!Domain Administrators

>    server1.loc.mydomain.com!Administrator!JohnDoe!Support!Domain Administrators

Comment: Remove the whole `foreach(){}` loop, just do it once

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you also help do have some regex in place so I don't have to execute manually for each server1, server2, server3 etc..

I tried the basic $number = Select-String d{0,3} and by adding $strComputer = “server" + $number +".loc.mydomain.com” but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the output to have all accounts in one line, change the `foreach()` loop at the bottom to just:

```
$a = @($strComputer;$members) -join '!'
LogToFile "C:\local-admins.txt" $a
```

To generate a list of servers with successive numbers in their name, use the range operator `..`:

```
$serverNames = foreach($number in 1..38){
    'server{0}' -f $number
}
```

So you end up with something like:

```
function LogToFile ([string]$strFileName, [string]$strComputer)
{
    Add-Content $strFileName $strComputer
}

foreach($ServerNumber in 1..38){
    $ServerName = 'server{0}.loc.mydomain.com' -f $ServerNumber
    $Computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://$ServerName,computer")
    $Group = $Computer.psbase.children.Find('Administrators')
    $Members= $Group.psbase.invoke('Members') |ForEach-Object { $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) }

    $Output = @($ServerName;$members) -join '!'
    LogToFile 'C:\local-admins.txt' $Output
}
```

Comment: *wrongly clicked the Edit button above. No changes made to @Mathias' code. Thanks